# MySQL: Naming a field AS madeupfield and performing a WHERE on that field

Tags: mysql

I have a statement like this:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(DATE(`starttime`),' ',HOUR(`starttime`),':',LPAD(1*(MINUTE(`starttime`) DIV 1),2,'0'),':00') AS date
FROM
  `times`
```

It's the where clause that I am having trouble with because it has to be something like:

```
WHERE
  `date` IN ('2011-06-05 11:00:00', '2011-06-05 12:00:00')
```

In this statement I correctly can't use `date` as the WHERE clause because it doesn't exist.

Does anyone know what I do instead?

Thanks in advance,

H.

Comment: What format is `starttime` in currently?  Can you provide that in your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(DATE(`starttime`),' ',HOUR(`starttime`),':',LPAD(1*(MINUTE(`starttime`) DIV 1),2,'0'),':00') AS date
FROM
  `times`

HAVING 
    `date` IN ('2011-06-05 11:00:00', '2011-06-05 12:00:00')
```